# What is the difference between MulticlassClassificationEvaluator and MultilabelClassificationEvaluator in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, multiclass-classification

[MulticlassClassificationEvaluator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator.html#pyspark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator) and [MultilabelClassificationEvaluator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.evaluation.MultilabelClassificationEvaluator.html#pyspark.ml.evaluation.MultilabelClassificationEvaluator)
are two (of many) Classification Algorithm Evaluators found in PySpark.
I can't find/ understand the difference between these two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [first one](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator.html#pyspark.ml.evaluation.MulticlassClassificationEvaluator) is for evaluation of the models that classifies given data into a specific single class (label), but model works with multiple classes (labels) (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification)). For example, you can categorize web site as online shop, business, gaming, health, etc.

The [second](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.evaluation.MultilabelClassificationEvaluator.html#pyspark.ml.evaluation.MultilabelClassificationEvaluator) is for case when the data may belong to multiple classes and multiple labels (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification)).  Continuing example of web sites, for example, site that sells pharmacy online may could be classified as both "online shop" and "health"